# Conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

The error occurs when saving the object couple.

### Code

**Data class**

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public bool IsBlock { get; set; }
    public bool IsGuest { get; set; }
    public string CodeGuest { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Birth { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual Couple Couple { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}


public class Couple
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string UrlKeyword { get; set; }
    public virtual User Groom { get; set; }
    public virtual User Bride { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Marriage { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Dating { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Engagement { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public Couple()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

**Context and configurations**

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    #region Collections

    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Couple> Couples { get; set; }

    #endregion

    public DataContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new AndMarriedInitializer());

        if (!Database.CreateIfNotExists())
            Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id).
            Property(p => p.Id)
                .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.FirstName)
            .HasMaxLength(60)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.LastName)
            .HasMaxLength(120)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.Email)
            .HasMaxLength(120)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.Password)
            .HasMaxLength(60);

        Property(p => p.CodeGuest)
            .HasMaxLength(60);

        HasRequired(u => u.Couple).WithRequiredPrincipal();
    }
}

public class CoupleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Couple>
{
    public CoupleConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id)
            .Property(p => p.Id)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.UrlKeyword)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(25);

        HasRequired(p => p.Groom).WithRequiredPrincipal().WillCascadeOnDelete();
        HasRequired(p => p.Bride).WithRequiredPrincipal().WillCascadeOnDelete();
    }
}

public class AndMarriedInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DataContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(DataContext context)
    {
        context.Roles.Add(new Role
                              {
                                  Name = Constants.RoleAdmin
                              });
        context.Roles.Add(new Role
                              {
                                  Name = Constants.RoleCouple
                              });
        context.Roles.Add(new Role
                              {
                                  Name = Constants.RoleGuest
                              });

        context.SaveChanges();

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

### Question

Do not know if configured correctly, but we relate to the Couple with User is: 1 to 1.

Do not quite understand how the `WithRequiredPrincipal` and `WithRequiredDependent`

### Error

**On SaveChanges()**  =>

`The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "User_Couple". The conflict occurred in database "andmarried", table "dbo.Users", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.`

Answer (score 0):

With this line of code:

```
public UserConfiguration()
{
//...
    HasRequired(u => u.Couple).WithRequiredPrincipal();
//...
```

You're requiring all users to be "coupled" all the time.

So, when you commit your changes, are all the users you created married?  If not, remove that foreign key constraint.  (Just leave the couple ones in and you should be O.K.)

Comment: Yes, but what I want is that every user is associated with a couple.
What defines whether it is a couple or a guest are the roles;

Comment: In any case, it sounds like you're committing a database state where a User exists with no couple.  Perhaps auto-commit is a problem?  Can you show the code actually making the calls into these objects?  ie: What is being created and saved and then the actual line that fails with an exception?
Note: User <-> Couple sounds like either 2 <-> 1 or maybe many <-> 1 based on your last comment.

Comment: `public Couple Add(Couple entity)
{
 // Add Roles
 var role = (from r in RoleRepository.GetAll()
    where r.Name == Constants.RoleCouple
    select r).SingleOrDefault();


 entity.Bride.Roles.Add(role);
 entity.Groom.Roles.Add(role);

 //entity.Users.Add(entity.Bride);  //Problem here
 //entity.Users.Add(entity.Groom);  //Problem here

 return Repository.Add(entity);
}`  See the `//Problem here` line
Do not know if I leave this line commented out, or remove comment.
The relationship is 2 couples for 1 user

Comment: If I remove the comment the following error occurs:
`Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.`

Comment: Have you tried WithMany() for the user <-> couple relationship?

Comment: `HasRequired(u => u.Couple).WithMany();` in `UserConfiguration` class
**Error on SaveChanges()**
`Entities in 'DataContext.Users' participate in the 'User_Couple' relationship. 0 related 'User_Couple_Target' were found. 1 'User_Couple_Target' is expected.`

Comment: Reading this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165720/Using-the-Code-First-Model-Configuration-Classes?display=Print Looks like a list of Users in the other object is the expected way to do the one to many.  Also, for the two-way relationship it looks like you have to use the form of With*** that takes in the function.  Sorry I'm not more helpful.

Comment: I do not understand what I'm doing wrong. The relationship is relatively simple: a couple will always have two users, yet thanks for the tip, I'll read the article!

Comment: **Table** `Couples:
ID
GroomID -> UserID
BrideID -> UserID`


**Table** `User:
ID
CoupleID`

----------
Couple `Class
Guid ID
User Groom
User Bride`

User `class
Guid ID
Couple Couple`

-------------
**for each couple there are two users, ever!**